# Add two columns values with ',' between them only if none of the cells is null

Tags: python, pandas, cell, addition

I have the following dataframe:

```
>>>name   breakfast  lunch   dinner
0 Zoey    apple      egg     noodels
1 Rena    pear               pasta
2 Shila             tomato  potatoes
3 Daphni coffee             soup 
4 Dufi
```

I would like to create new column which will have all the food values that each name ate on the same day. I have tried to do it using '+'  and seperate between the words with ',' as following:

```
df['food']=df['breakfast']+','+df['lunch']+','+df['dinner']
```

but then if I have null values I have ',' in the middle:

```
>>>name   breakfast  lunch   dinner     food
0 Zoey    apple      egg     noodels    apple,egg,noodels
1 Rena    pear               pasta      pear,,pasta
2 Shila             tomato  potatoes    ,tmatoe,potatoes
3 Daphni coffee             soup       coffee,,soupp
4. Dufi                                ,,
```

and I would like to get it clean with ',' in the right places, e.g not to put , if there is null:

```
>>>name   breakfast  lunch   dinner     food
0 Zoey    apple      egg     noodels    apple,egg,noodels
1 Rena    pear               pasta      pear,pasta
2 Shila             tomato  potatoes    tmatoe,potatoes
3 Daphni coffee             soup       coffee,soup
4 Dufi
```

is there any way to do this ? to define that if there is null cell do not add it/ don't put , in wrong places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution if no missing values, only empty strings is joined only values filtering empty strings:

```
cols = ['breakfast','lunch','dinner']
df['food'] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: ','.join(y for y in x if y != ''), axis=1)
print (df)
     name breakfast   lunch    dinner               food
0    Zoey     apple     egg   noodels  apple,egg,noodels
1    Rena      pear             pasta         pear,pasta
2   Shila            tomato  potatoes    tomato,potatoes
3  Daphni    coffee              soup        coffee,soup
4   Dufi
```

Or with list comprehension:

```
cols = ['breakfast','lunch','dinner']
df['food'] = [','.join(y for y in x if y != '') for x in df[cols].to_numpy()]
print (df)
     name breakfast   lunch    dinner               food
0    Zoey     apple     egg   noodels  apple,egg,noodels
1    Rena      pear             pasta         pear,pasta
2   Shila            tomato  potatoes    tomato,potatoes
3  Daphni    coffee              soup        coffee,soup
4   Dufi
```

Solution if missing values is similar only use `NaN != NaN`:

```
cols = ['breakfast','lunch','dinner']
df['food'] = [','.join(y for y in x if y == y) for x in df[cols].to_numpy()]
print (df)
     name breakfast   lunch    dinner               food
0    Zoey     apple     egg   noodels  apple,egg,noodels
1    Rena      pear     NaN     pasta         pear,pasta
2   Shila       NaN  tomato  potatoes    tomato,potatoes
3  Daphni    coffee     NaN      soup        coffee,soup
4   Dufi        NaN     NaN       NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

use `.stack` with `groupby` on your index.

assuming your blanks are actually true nulls

since, we don't want name, we can either add it to the index or drop it, i've added it here.

```
df['food'] = df.set_index('name',append=True).stack().groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
```

if your blanks are not nulls we can do

```
df.replace(' ', np.nan).set_index('name',append=True).stack()\
                       .groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
```

---

```
    name breakfast     lunch   dinner               food
0    Zoey     apple       egg  noodels  apple,egg,noodels
1    Rena      pear     pasta      NaN         pear,pasta
2   Shila    tomato  potatoes      NaN    tomato,potatoes
3  Daphni    coffee      soup      NaN        coffee,soup
4    Dufi       NaN       NaN      NaN                NaN
```